# Color disappears when light is used in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

```cpp
glLoadIdentity();               
glTranslatef(0.0f + deltaA - deltaD, 0.0f + deltaQ - deltaE, 0.0f + deltaW - deltaS);
glRotatef(_rotate_x, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(_rotate_y, 0, 1, 0);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glutSolidSphere(20, 15, 15);
```

[image]

If I write the code like this, the red color looks good.

```cpp
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

glLoadIdentity();               
glTranslatef(0.0f + deltaA - deltaD, 0.0f + deltaQ - deltaE, 0.0f + deltaW - deltaS);
glRotatef(_rotate_x, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(_rotate_y, 0, 1, 0);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glutSolidSphere(20, 15, 15);

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

[image]

But if I use a light like this, it's white. What's the reason?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Basic OpenGL Lighting](https://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html). When lighting ([`GL_LIGHTING`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)) is enabled, the render color is taken from the material parameters ([`glMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMaterial.xml)). If you still want to use the current color attribute (set by [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)), you need to enable [`GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)
and to set the color material parameters ([`glColorMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml)):

```cpp
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
```